# How to move Dashboard, work items, CI/CD pipelines , test plans and iteration from one Team project to another

Tags: azure-devops, migration, team-project

I have a requirement to split one big Team project in Azure DevOps to multiple team projects, as you know there are work items, iteration , repositories, test plans and CI/CD pipelines to move across. What is the best way of achieving this - apart from manually moving them across ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no default way to move sources from one Team project to another. You can check [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility) which can migrate source code, work items, etc.

Meanwhile, there are [move work items (select some work items > Right click > Move) to another team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items#move-a-work-item-to-another-team-project), [move git repositories between team projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/move-git-repos-between-team-projects), [move items in TFVC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/rename-move-files-folders) features that can help move sources.